# Simple python inheritance with singleton class failing with no stack trace

Tags: python, class, exception, inheritance

```py
class B:
    @property
    def x(self):
        print('x getter')
        return self.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x) -> None:
        print('x setter')
        self.x = x + 1

class A(B):
    __instance = None
    def __new__(self):
        ''' Virtually private constructor '''
        if not A.__instance:
            A.__instance = object.__new__(self)
            A.__instance.__setup()

        return A.__instance
    
    def __setup(self):
        self.x = 10
    
    def minus(self):
        self.x -= 3

a1 = A()
```

Class `A` is a singleton class.

I'm not sure what is causing the program to fail as there is no stack trace and it just fails.

Comment: btw I get `RecursionError` when I run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `@property` and setter correctly. You need a different name for the actual underlying property:

```py
class B:
    @property
    def x(self):
        print('x getter')
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x) -> None:
        print('x setter')
        self._x = x + 1
```